# $K(\ell^2)\cong C(G)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K(\ell^2)$ be the set of compact operators on $\ell^2$. Is there a compact Hausdorff space $G$ such that $K(\ell^2)\cong C(G)$? I was doing some searching, and it I saw someone claim that if $X$ is a non-unital $C*$ algebra, then its unit ball has no extreme points. If this is true, then I suppose the answer to my question would be no, since $C(G)$ will have some (but finitely many) extreme points. Is this correct?

Comment: When you write $\cong$ you mean isomorphism as $C^*$ algebras or as Banach spaces? The former is impossible simply because $K(\ell^2)$ is not commutative and not unital, but $C(G)$ is both.

Comment: As Banach spaces

Comment: Okay. In that case, you should also specify whether a Banach space isomorphism needs to be isometric. If so, your argument using extreme points works fine. If not, keep in mind that there are Banach spaces that are linearly isomorphic but not isometrically, so extreme points are not preserved (for example $c$ and $c_0$)